# _core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm Incorrect parameter value for TARGET_LAYER

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I am working on a QGIS plugin using Python with Plugin builder and QT designer with two algorithms inside "Points to Path" and "Append Features to Layer".

My plugin takes a CSV and then converts it to a line using "Points to Path" and then I would like to automatically make a connection with my PostGreSQL database and add it to a table. It works well inside the python console but when trying to add this line to my CSR table it keeps failing and I don't know how to parametrize it well.

Anybody can help me with this problem? I provide a little piece of my code for exemplifying myself:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
import os
from functools import partial
# Import necessary modules
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject, QgsRectangle, QgsFeature, QgsDataSourceUri, QgsProcessing
from osgeo import ogr
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

from .first_plugin_dialog import FirstPluginDialog
from qgis import processing
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
from AppendFeaturesToLayer.append_features_to_layer_plugin import AppendFeaturesToLayerPlugin

class FirstPlugin():
#here it does some of the funcionality of the plugin and in some point...

   def apply_button(self):
#Now we are going to append this layer to our CSR database using append to features:
            dbname = self.dlg.database_name.text()
            host = self.dlg.host_name.text()
            port = self.dlg.port.text()
            user = self.dlg.user_name.text()
            password = self.dlg.password.text()
            table_name = self.dlg.table_name.text()
            target_layer = f" 'dbname=\'{dbname}\' host={host} port={port}\' user=\'{user}\' password=\'{password}\' key=\'id\' srid=4326 type=MultiLineString checkPrimaryKeyUnicity=\'1\' table={table_name}"
            print(target_layer)
            param_2 = {
                'SOURCE_LAYER': layer_2,
                'SOURCE_FIELD': '',
                'TARGET_LAYER': target_layer,
                'TARGET_FIELD': '',
                'ACTION_ON_DUPLICATE':0
                }
        
            processing.run("etl_load:appendfeaturestolayer", param_2)
            print(f'Your new {name} was successfully added to your CSR database table')
            iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
            iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(extent)
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Success", "You've''successfully added your new layer to CSR table !", level=QgsMessageBar.Success)
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own issue passing target_layer as an URI layer doing:

```
# Define the connection parameters using QgsDataSourceUri
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(host, port, dbname, user, password)

# Set the table name and key field
uri.setDataSource('public', table_name, 'geom', '', 'id')

# Create the layer using the constructed URI
target_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), table_name, 'postgres')
```

And there is no problem anymore. Hope it can help others in parsing connections inside of any type of QGIS algorithm.